# Android Animations - Animate view to a specific position

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, objectanimator

I have a load screen/pop up screen which is a fragment which shows up whenever I call an API. I like how it looks currently, but I would like to liven it up by adding a bunch of animations to the views in the load screen.

I am using the property animation framework to good effect for 
scaling and changing the alpha value(transparency) of views in their current positions.

I am now trying to get a view to animate(translate + alpha change) to it's current position in the static screen. I do not however, wish to hardcode values since this would clearly mess up the alignment of views and cause overlaps and other problems.

How do I translate a view from some point outside the screen, to it's current position in the static screen? Eg: In my static screen if I have a view that is centre aligned in the parent layout, how do I animate the view from a position outside the screen to this current position. I have tried the following but it does not work since it expects float values.

```
    <set android:ordering="together">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1500"
        android:propertyName="y"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="50%p"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1500"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</set>
```

I am trying to keep as much of the animation logic in xmls as possible.

Comment: Can the person who down voted please suggest an edit or at least why it was down voted? This is getting ridiculous since this is the second animation related question I have posted that has been down voted.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more research I came across the translationY(and translation X) attribute which seems to be the one I was looking for.